# Hbase Shell could start, however error thrown. Unable to load jetty, not starting JettyAdminServer

Tags: hadoop, jetty, hbase

I am a newbie of Hadoop and HBase. I have successfully installed and started Hadoop and started HBase Shell, however, I could not use the shell in a normal way.
After starting Hadoop and HBase, the Java Virtual Machine Process Status looks like this:

```
> jps
152193 NameNode
152983 NodeManager
157908 Jps
154059 HMaster
152809 ResourceManager
152393 DataNode
```

which presumably spells that Hadoop is running successfully.
However, after entering `status` in HBase Shell, errors occurred like these:

```
Version 2.4.15, r35310fcd6b11a1d04d75eb7db2e592dd34e4d5b6, Thu Oct 13 11:42:20 PDT 2022
Took 0.0020 seconds                                                             
hbase:001:0> status

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ServerNotRunningYetException: Server is not running yet
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkServiceStarted(HMaster.java:2804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.isMasterRunning(MasterRpcServices.java:1163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:349)

For usage try 'help "status"'

Took 9.1426 seconds                                                             
hbase:002:0>
```

In order to find out the reason, I looked up the log `hbase-hadoop-zookeeper-TencentCloudHongKong.log`, which shows:

```
2023-03-07 04:06:12,252 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Created server with tickTime 3000 minSessionTimeout 6000 maxSessionTimeout 90000 datadir ./tmp/zookeeper/version-2 snapdir ./tmp/zookeeper/version-2
2023-03-07 04:06:12,253 WARN  [main] admin.AdminServerFactory: Unable to load jetty, not starting JettyAdminServer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.admin.AdminServerFactory.createAdminServer(AdminServerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.runZKServer(HQuorumPeer.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.main(HQuorumPeer.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 6 more
2023-03-07 04:06:12,261 INFO  [main] server.ServerCnxnFactory: Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory
2023-03-07 04:06:12,262 INFO  [main] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Configuring NIO connection handler with 10s sessionless connection timeout, 1 selector thread(s), 8 worker threads, and 64 kB direct buffers.
2023-03-07 04:06:12,269 INFO  [main] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2023-03-07 04:16:48,112 WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-5] server.NIOServerCnxn: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x10000b674f50012, likely client has closed socket
```

It seems that the problem is related to `JettyAdminServer`. Should I check something like classpath and include `jetty` in? Could you please tell me whether there are proper solutions? Thank you very much.

Note that existing answers might not help and both port 8080 and 50070 work normally.